# How to get XML node angular brace in Value

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want my XML node as :

```
<Name><![CDATA[Masonry, Stucco &amp; Brick Paint]]></Name>
```

But it is getting saved as :

```
<Name>&lt;![CDATA[Abcd, City &amp; Abcd]]&gt;</Name>
```

I am using code like:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
...
...
Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("<![CDATA[" + categoryName + "]]>"));
category.appendChild(name);
```

> I even tried using "amp;lt;" and "amp;gt;" for < and > respectively but does not works

Comment: if so please accept/vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
class StringToDocumentToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String xmlStr = "<Name><![CDATA[Masonry, Stucco &amp; Brick Paint]]></Name>";

        Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlStr); //You can directly store this document as .xml but if you want String as return than do next step
        String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    private static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc) {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
            String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
            return output;
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    xmlStr)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```